# My UTF-8 file is auto converted to ANSI, how can I fix this?

Tags: python, windows, encoding

I am making an input file for another program using Python3.6, and my OS is Windows 10, my output code like this:

```
with open(TXT_DESTINATION, 'w', encoding='utf-8', newline='\n') as output:
    output.write(mythings)
```

When I open this output file with EditPlus, it always tells me that it is encoded using ANSI. And the program that takes this file as an input will also raise error. (Strange, Notepad++ tells the file is UTF-8 encoded)

However, if I put a character like Ž Ǧ, the file will keep UTF-8 encoding and the program works fine. It is very annoying and I just can't figure out why and how to fix this?

Comment: For the lowest 127 characters, ANSI and utf-8 are binary identical. This is part of the design of UTF-8.

As a result they will only appear different if you have a codepoint above 127.

Comment: @Dragonthoughts But the program takes this as an input will raise errors although the lowest 127 characters are identical, after adding some non-English character it works fine

Comment: Your editor and target program should have a way to override the detected encoding to force using UTF-8. Detection is heuristic based and thus not completely reliable. If it doesn't have an option to force using UTF-8, then try saving the file with a UTF-8 byte order mark. (Technically this is pointless since UTF-8 is a byte stream, but it works as a kind of magic number to identify the encoding.) In Python this is the "utf-8-sig" encoding.

Comment: Or put early on text some UTF-8 characters (not in ANSI). Heuristic usually involves just very first part of text.